# Zstd decompress with Armv7 32bit performance is too poor

Tags: compression, 32-bit, armv7, zstd

I am using ZStd with armv7 32bit platform to decompress, but 128M data would require about 2 minutes to finish. But on armv8 64bit, it is only require about 2seconds, so what result armv7 32bit performance so poor.

I have find zstd mem.h have said using unalign memory access can speed the decompress, but i have setting sctlr.a bit to 0 , it is still no effect

Comment: OK, and what is your question?

Comment: I want to know what i needs to set or how i can make it normal as 64bit